# Check if 2 arrays are same or not (C++)

Tags: c++

I want to compare two int arrays and find if they are the same and if they are not i want to find the min and the max number that exist in one but not in the other. I use this code in c++ but seems to run into a segmentation fault 11. I would be grateful if someone points out the mistake to me.I would like to see better solutions if there are any.
+ I did the mergesort for time limit of 1 second.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void merge(int *a,int s,int e)
{
  int mid = (s+e)/2;
  int i = s;
  int j = mid+1;
  int k = s;
  int temp[100];
  while(i<=mid && j<=e)
  {
    if(a[i] < a[j])
    {
      temp[k++] = a[i++];
    }
    else
    {
      temp[k++] = a[j++];
    }
  }
  while(i<=mid)
  {
    temp[k++] = a[i++];
  }
  while(j<=e)
  {
    temp[k++]  = a[j++];
  }
  for(int i=s;i<=e;i++)
  {
    a[i] = temp[i];
  }
}

void mergeSort(int a[],int s,int e)
{
  if(s>=e)
  {
    return;
  }
  int mid = (s+e)/2;
  mergeSort(a,s,mid);
  mergeSort(a,mid+1,e);
  merge(a,s,e);
}
int min_array (int array1[],int n1)
{
  int min = array1[0];
  for(int i=1;i<n1;i++)
    if(array1[i] < min)
      min = array1[i];
  return min;
}

int max_array (int array2[],int n2)
{
  int max = array2[0];
  for(int i=1;i<n2;i++)
    if(array2[i] > max)
      max = array2[i];
  return max;
}

void check_same(int a[], int b[], int n)
{
  bool check = true;
  int check1 = 2, check2 = 2, counter1 = 0, counter2 = 0, i, j;
  int pos1[n], pos2[n];
  mergeSort(a, 0, n);
  mergeSort(b, 0, n);
  for(i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    if (a[i] != b[i])
      check = false;
    for(j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
      if (a[i] != b[j])
        check1 = 0;
      else if (a[i] == b[j])
        check1 = 1;
      else if (a[j] != b[i])
        check2 = 0;
      else if (a[j] == b[i])
        check2 = 1;
      if (check1 == 1 && check2 == 1)
        break;
    }
    if (check1 == 0)
        pos1[counter1++] = i;
    else if (check2 == 0)
      pos2[counter2++] = i;

  }
  int differents[counter1 + counter2];
  if (counter1 < counter2)
  {
    for (i=0; i<counter1; i++)
      differents[i] = a[pos1[i]];
    for (i=counter1; i<counter2; i++)
      differents[i] = b[pos2[counter2 - i]];
  }
  else
  {
    for (i=0; i<counter2; i++)
      differents[i] = b[pos2[i]];
    for (i=counter2; i<counter1; i++)
      differents[i] = a[pos1[counter1 - i]];
  }
  if (check)
    cout << "yes\n";
  else if (check == false)
    cout << "no " << min_array(differents, counter1+counter2)<< " " << max_array(differents, counter1+counter2) << endl;
}

int main()
{
  int N, i;
  cin >> N;
  int A[50000], B[50000];
  for (i=0;i<N;i++)
    cin >> A[i];
  for (i=0;i<N;i++)
    cin >> B[i];
  check_same(A, B, N);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean "same" as contain the same elements *in the same order* or just contain the same elements, but possibly in different order?

Comment: If you really want to do what you state, this is basically 3 lines of C++ code using `std::sort`, and `std::mismatch`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie And `std::symmetric_difference` + `std::minmax_element`

Comment: @Corristo Yes, those functions also.  Unless you're coding in `C`, where none of these nice functions and algorithms exist (thus you have to create them), there really is no need to write all of this code for a C++ solution.

Comment: Do you have to return `min and the max number` or `max and min index`?

Comment: Even merge sort is doable with just a few lines of code using `std::inplace_merge`.  Bottom line -- learn your [STL algorithm functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm)

Comment: i am talking about same elements not order nor length

Comment: I want to return the min and the max element of the different elements in both arrays.

Comment: @AntonisDouk Can array have duplicacies? If yes, If `A=[10, 10, 20, 30, 40]` and `B=[10, 30, 31, 32, 33]`, What is the output?

Comment: No duplicates each array has unique elements

Comment: @AntonisDouk Please consider my solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not standard C++, the line `int pos1[n], pos2[n];` in `check_same` is invalid because `n` is not a compile time constant - VLAs are only allowed in C.

You could make use of the standard library for all of that:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

void check_same(int a[], int b[], int n) {
    std::sort(a, a + n);
    std::sort(b, b + n);

    if(std::equal(a, a + n, b)) {
        std::cout << "yes\n";
    } else {
        std::vector<int> elements_not_in_both;
        std::set_symmetric_difference(a, a + n, 
                                      b, b + n,
                                      std::back_inserter(elements_not_in_both));
        auto [min, max] = std::minmax_element(elements_not_in_both.cbegin(),
                                              elements_not_in_both.cend());
        std::cout << "no " << *min << " " << *max << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    int N;
    std::cin >> N;
    int A[50000], B[50000];
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        std::cin >> A[i];
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        std::cin >> B[i];
    check_same(A, B, N);
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pxZzviLhP5rEUPuu).

An even better solution is to not use C-style arrays either, then you don't allocate way too much stack space for small input arrays and you can't have too little space when someone decides to run this on more than 50000 elements:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

void check_same(std::vector<int>& a, std::vector<int>& b) {
    std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    std::sort(b.begin(), b.end());

    if(a == b) {
        std::cout << "yes\n";
     } else {
        std::vector<int> elements_not_in_both;
        std::set_symmetric_difference(a.cbegin(), a.cend(), 
                                      b.cbegin(), b.cend(),
                                      std::back_inserter(elements_not_in_both));
        auto [min, max] = std::minmax_element(elements_not_in_both.cbegin(),
                                              elements_not_in_both.cend());
        std::cout << "no " << *min << " " << *max << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    int N;
    std::cin >> N;

    std::vector<int> a, b;
    a.reserve(N);
    b.reserve(N);

    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), N, std::back_inserter(a));
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), N, std::back_inserter(b));

    check_same(a, b);
}
```

Comment: Ok but shouldnt my mistake be mentioned in the compile section?

Comment: @AntonisDouk Your mistake with the variable-length arrays is one of my major complaints with g++ and compilers that accept that syntax by default -- it makes new programmers believe they are writing valid C++ code when actually they're not.  On the other hand, Visual Studio would definitely fail to compile your code using that array syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out for these points for solving segmentation fault issue:

**merge function**

1) Is this statement `int k = s;` correct? Shouldn't it be `int k = 0;`

2) Is this allocation `int temp[100];` OK? Or Should it be `int temp[e - s + 1]`;

3) Is this statement `a[i] = temp[i];` correct? Shouldn't it be `a[i] = temp[i - s];`

4) Do you need to have base condition `s < e` or something? i.e. Handling the case when `s == e`.

**check_same function**

1) Is this call `mergeSort(a, 0, n);` correct? Shouldn't it be `mergeSort(a, 0, n - 1);`

As far as better approach is concerned, it can be solved in O(n) using hashing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace std;

void check_same(int a[], int b[], int n) {
    int minNotInA, maxNotInA, minNotInB, maxNotInB;
    bool elementMissingInA = false, elementMissingInB = false;

    {
        unordered_set<int> elementsInB;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            elementsInB.insert(b[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (elementsInB.find(a[i]) == elementsInB.end()) {
                if (!elementMissingInA) {
                    elementMissingInA = true;
                    minNotInB = maxNotInB = a[i];
                } else {
                    if (minNotInB > a[i]) {
                        minNotInB = a[i];
                    } else if (maxNotInB < a[i]) {
                        maxNotInB = a[i];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (elementMissingInA) {
        unordered_set<int> elementsInA;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            elementsInA.insert(a[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (elementsInA.find(b[i]) == elementsInA.end()) {
                if (!elementMissingInB) {
                    elementMissingInB = true;
                    minNotInA = maxNotInA = b[i];
                } else {
                    if (minNotInA > b[i]) {
                        minNotInA = b[i];
                    } else if (maxNotInA < b[i]) {
                        maxNotInA = b[i];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (elementMissingInA and elementMissingInB) {
        cout << "no " << min(minNotInA, minNotInB) << " " << max(maxNotInA, maxNotInB) << "\n";
    } else {
        cout << "yes\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    int N;
    std::cin >> N;
    int A[50000], B[50000];
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        std::cin >> A[i];
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        std::cin >> B[i];
    check_same(A, B, N);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank all of you for your interest and your help.
Because i am not used to those kinds of libraries you use and i dont want to study them at the moment(i am just in the first semester of my ece class) i corrected my code(both improved it and fixed the segmentation fault 11)
You can take a look right here.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void merge(int *a, int s, int e)
{
    int mid = (s + e) / 2;
    int i = s;
    int j = mid + 1;
    int k = s;
    int temp[50000];
    while (i <= mid && j <= e)
    {
        if (a[i] < a[j])
        {
            temp[k++] = a[i++];
        }
        else
        {
            temp[k++] = a[j++];
        }
    }
    while (i <= mid)
    {
        temp[k++] = a[i++];
    }
    while (j <= e)
    {
        temp[k++] = a[j++];
    }
    for (int i = s; i <= e; i++)
    {
        a[i] = temp[i];
    }
}

void mergeSort(int a[], int s, int e)
{
    if (s >= e)
    {
        return;
    }
    int mid = (s + e) / 2;
    mergeSort(a, s, mid);
    mergeSort(a, mid + 1, e);
    merge(a, s, e);
}
int min_array(int array1[], int n1)
{
    int min = array1[0];
    for (int i = 1; i<n1; i++)
        if (array1[i] < min)
            min = array1[i];
    return min;
}

int max_array(int array2[], int n2)
{
    int max = array2[0];
    for (int i = 1; i<n2; i++)
        if (array2[i] > max)
            max = array2[i];
    return max;
}


void check_same(int a[], int b[], int n)
{
    int differents[50000];
    int counter1 = 0, counter2 = 0;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (i < n && j < n)
    {
        if (a[i] < b[j])
        {
            differents[counter1++ + counter2] = a[i];
            i++;
        }
        else if (b[j] < a[i])
        {
            differents[counter2++ + counter1] = b[j];
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    if (counter1 == 0 && counter2 == 0)
        cout << "yes\n";
    else 
        cout << "no " << min_array(differents, counter1 + counter2) << " " << max_array(differents, counter1 + counter2) << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int A[50000], B[50000];
    int N, i;
    cin >> N;
    for (i = 0; i<N; i++)
        cin >> A[i];
    for (i = 0; i<N; i++)
        cin >> B[i];
    mergeSort(A, 0, N-1);
    mergeSort(B, 0, N-1);
    check_same(A, B, N);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "i am just in the first semester of my ece class": Unfortunately, the state of C++ education is really bad. In an ideal world you wouldn't even have learnt about C-style arrays in an introductory course until after you learned about `std::vector` and `std::array`, and at least `std::sort` should've been shown beforehand when you're expected to sort data in an assignment. If you like C++ and would like to learn it properly instead of the "C with classes" style that is still commonly taught at universities, consider one of the books recommended here on StackOverflow.

Comment: I dont know if you are right or wrong but i am sure that education is really bad generally and if you want to learn sth you are all by yourself and the research you make by your own ... so i will check the books you are talking about and see what i can get out of them. Thank you again for your interest.

Comment: *i am just in the first semester of my ece class* -- Believe it or not, that should have been the *best* time to learn proper C++ instead of `C` with classes.  You would have, from the start, learn about the containers and algorithms.  For example, you would have known that to sort items you use `std::sort`, to get the minimum and maximum, you simply use `std::min_element`, std::max_element` or `std::minmax_element` for a combination of both of those functions.

Comment: `differents[counter1++ + counter2] = a[i];`  -- This is undefined behavior.  There is no guarantee what the order is of the addition.  You assumed left to right, but the compiler can choose right to left.